# Read values from a Config file for playwright.net tests

Tags: c#, testing, playwright-test

I want to load config file for a playwright.net test written in C#. for instance, username, headless mode etc. I m not sure if i need to add an appsettings or just a config file and add these parameters? I tried with a config file using a config file with key value pairs and then adding this to the script: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], but this doesnt work. How is it used? appsettings.json or App.config. I m writing a playwright.net test using c# with .net core. Please advise or provide any examples to follow

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a global configuration for Playwright .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169501/how-do-you-create-a-global-configuration-for-playwright-net)

Comment: No sorry. i m using .net with c#.

Comment: That question is also about .net.

Comment: In the answer, it says create playwright.config.js which is javascript not c#. for reference, this is the foramt of my playwright script:    public Task LoginUsername() => Page.ClickAsync("id=UserID");

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the configuration in your unit tests. This post will give you direction: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-configuration-files-in-dotnet-core-unit-tests/

This is the TLDR version:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("client-secrets.json")
    .Build();

var clientId = config["AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"]
```

Comment: Thanks but I m not writing unit tests. i m using specflow with playwright.net for BDD tests. I have a feature folder, Steps folder, Hooks and pageObjects folder. how do i add the username and other parameters to the config file? this is one of the lines in the test script:  public Task LoginUsername() => Page.ClickAsync("id=UserID")

Comment: Ok i got it to work now. but i need it to be in separate class or method rather than the same method:    public async Task Login()
        {

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
           .Build();
            string username = config["Login:Username"];

Comment: The first line in the question says "I want to load config file for a playwright.net **test** written in C#" ?  - regardless, if my answer did indeed answer your question - would you mind ticking the button to reflect that? Thanks!

Comment: Yes sure I will. I just just cant see the tick option? I would say yes it has answered the question partially. it just it needs to be separate from the builder method. So this variable will be used in a separate method and that;s where i  m stuck with it. var clientId = config["AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"]